# Document content getting aligned vertically when pasting algorithm

Tags: equations, algorithms, alignment

Everything in my document is getting aligned vertically after pasting this algorithm code in my document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

 % For reducing margin
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{arevmath}     % For math symbols
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\title{Algorithm template}
\author{Ajay}

\date{\today}    % Today's date

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \centering
  \caption{RL-training Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{RL-Training}{Document $D$, Training step $T$, Batch size $B$}
      \State Initialize  network params $\theta$
      \For{$t = 1$ to $T$}
        \State Sample input sentence $s_{i}$ from document D  for $i \in \{1, \ldots, B\}$
        \State Calculate reward value by comparing ROUGE-L score between ground truth summary and predicted summary
        \State calculate gradient of loss as \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\nabla L(\theta)
& \approx-r(\hat{y}) \sum_{i=1}^{B} \nabla \log p\left(\hat{y}_{i} \mid s_{i}, D, \theta\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
        \State Normalize the gradient with Batch size 
        \begin{equation}
            g_\theta =  \frac{1}{B} \nabla L(\theta)
        \end{equation}
        
        \State update $\theta$ with adam optimizer 
        \begin{equation}
            \theta \gets \Call{Adam}{\theta, g_{\theta}}
        \end{equation}
\EndFor
  \State \Return $\theta$ \newline
  \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Normal behavior, [t] means "put it at the top of the page if possible," and latex puts the floating body in the middle when the page is a floating page.